# Metadata not updated after PHAssetChangeRequest

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, ciimage

I'm trying to update the metadata of a `PHAsset`, however, the image does not always update the metadata.

What I'm doing:

- downloading the latest image using `requestContentEditingInput`
- in the `PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions`, I'm setting `canHandleAdjustmentData` to return `false` to return the latest version of the photo
- getting the existing properties using the inputs `fullSizeImageURL`
- creating a new `CIImage` with updated properties using `settingProperties` (I've verified at this point that the new `CIImage` returned has the updated properties)
- writing a JPEG (`writeJPEGRepresentation`) to the `PHContentEditingOutput` `renderedContentURL`
- creating a `PHAdjustmentData` and adding it to the output
- creating a `PHAssetChangeRequest` with the output
- and performing all that inside `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges()`

Now, when I fetch the latest image using `requestContentEditingInput`, it does not have the new properties.

**However**, the `adjustmentData` from the PHAsset is the new `PHAdjustmentData` from above!

If I share the photo via Photos.app, the metadata is not there.

I should mention that I'm trying to set the title (`kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary`) and description (`kCGImagePropertyIPTCCaptionAbstract`) fields of IPTC data.